# php adds slashes when concatenating strign to generate mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Why is this:

```
$query = "SELECT Used, Date FROM table WHERE Name = '".$name."'";
```

Producing this:

```
'SELECT Used, Data FROM table WHERE Name =\'name_value\''
```

I checked php.ini and:

```
magic_qoutes_gpc = off
magic_quotes_sybase = off
magic_quotes_runtime = off
```

Edit:

The variable $name comes from select (drop-down menu) element through a jquery post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chart_handler.php",
    data: {'volumeName': $('select[name="Volumes"] option:selected').val()},        
    success: function (results){
        //console.log(results);
        alert(results);
        plotVolumeChart(results);
        }
});
```

And in `chart_handler.php` I have:

```
if (isset($_POST['volumeName'])){

    $name = $_POST["volumeName"];

    // The usual mysql connection stuff, then:

    $query = "SELECT `Used`, `Date` FROM `volumes2` WHERE `Name` = '".$name. "'";
```

for debugging and where I see the slashed being added:

```
    file_put_contents( 'output_debug_sql' . time() . '.log', var_export( $query, true));
```

Comment: why php.ini? just show us the value of `$name` and var_dump of `$query`

Comment: php isn't going to mangle your string like that. something ELSE is doing. e.g. you're passing the entire query through a quote function, instead of just the values.

Comment: looks right to me, the `'`s are escaped because the string is encapsulated by `'`

Comment: magic quotes only mangles data at the "input" stage (script startup, or data coming out of a database). it doesn't modify strings as you build them, or after you're build them.

Comment: $query = "SELECT `Used`, `Date` FROM `table` WHERE `Name` = '$name'";

produces the same thing.

Comment: @cmorrissey I think your right the quotes are escaped because the string is encapsulated by single quotes. but as you see I encapsulate the string by double quotes. so something somewhere is converting them to single quotes. what is it?

Comment: I think the big question is, why are you building queries this way instead of doing it properly with prepared statements?

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproducing your issue, and it seems that `var_export` is generating the backslash, because it simply wraps that output string with single quotation as follows:

```
var_export( $query);
```

Output:

```
'SELECT `Used`, `Date` FROM `volumes2` WHERE `Name` = \'test\''
```

But if you echo the variable instead:

```
$query = "SELECT `Used`, `Date` FROM `volumes2` WHERE `Name` = '".$name. "'";

echo $query;
```

This would be the output:

```
SELECT `Used`, `Date` FROM `volumes2` WHERE `Name` = 'test'
```

Which is exactly as expected. Another point that I noticed in your code is that you do not need to add the escape quotes (`), so the following query should do the job:

```
SELECT Used, Date FROM volumes2 WHERE Name = 'test';
```

I suggest to double check your query in either `phpmyadmin` or `MySql Workbench` before you use it in your code, just to make sure that nothing is missing.

I really don't see any problem with the jQuery part, and as a proof of concept implementation, the following snippet (test.php) should not generate any back-slashes when it executes the AJAX request and print the result out:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['volumeName'])){
    $name = $_POST["volumeName"];
    $query = "SELECT `Used`, `Date` FROM `volumes2` WHERE `Name` = '".$name. "'";
    echo $name."<br>";
    die();
}

?>


<select name="Volumes">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<div id="result">
</div>

<a href="javascript:submit_onclick()">Submit</a>

<script>

function submit_onclick()
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: {'volumeName': $('select[name="Volumes"] option:selected').val()},        
    success: function (results){
        //console.log(results);
        $("#result").html(results);
        }
});
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So try to:

1. Remove the escape quotes (```) and see if your problem is fixed.
2. Wrap your query with double quotation (") instead of single quotation ('), and this way `var_export` will not have to spit out the backslash. Do it as follows:

   ```
   $query = 'SELECT Used, Date FROM volumes2 WHERE Name = "'.$name. '"';
   ```

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I know you have magic_quotes_gpc=off but try using mysql_real_escape_string($variable) instead of just $variable. If it works then something else is going on.

Comment: This did not work:    


    $query = "SELECT `Used`, `Date` FROM `volumes2` WHERE `Name` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($volume) . "'";